# Image of the sum of two morphisms in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm having trouble understanding Lemma 6 [here](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=oQF9TLjCwfsC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22Im(f%2Bg)%22+abelian+category&source=bl&ots=8H_O6epGmq&sig=EuTKOuHKojP_yYpF8PSVhbefGGk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje_YjqwdHPAhUFx2MKHe3aB04Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Im(f%2Bg)%22%20abelian%20category&f=false). The part that I don't understand is where the author says that by definition $$\textrm{Im }f\ \cup\ \textrm{Im }g = \textrm{Im }(\nabla b).$$ I already saw that $\textrm{Im }f\subset\textrm{Im }(\nabla b)$ and $\textrm{Im }g\subset\textrm{Im }(\nabla b)$. But I can't see why the property defining the union of subobjects holds. Any hint? Thanks.

**Edit 1.** The definition of the union is the following: Suppose we have a family of subobjects $\{A_i\}$ of $A$. The union of the family is a subobject $A'$ of $A$ larger than every $A_i$ and satisfiying the following property: If we consider a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ and a subobject $B'$ of $B$ such that $f$ restricted to every $A_i$ may be factored through $B'$, then $f$ restricted to $A'$ may be factored through $B'$.

**Edit 2.** if we take the epi-mono factorizations $f=u_f p_f$, $g=u_g p_g$, then $b:\textrm{Im }f\oplus\textrm{Im }g\rightarrow B\oplus B$ Is the morphism given by $u_f\oplus u_g$ and $\nabla$ is the codiagonal. Here we are taking $f,g:A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: How is $\cup$ defined?

Comment: The definition of the union is on pages 33-34 of the same book

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read page 33.

Comment: @Antonio: What is $\nabla b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understand your question:

Let $u : S\to X$ and $v: T\to X$ be monomorphisms (the images of $f$ and $g$) and let $e:S\oplus T\to U $ and $w : U \to X$ be morphisms such that $me$ is the epi-mono factorisation of $\Delta (u \oplus v)$. We need to show that for any morphism $h: U \to B$ and any monomorphism $x : V\to B$ such that there exists $j : S\to V$ and $k : T\to V$ such that $xj = hei_1$ and $xk = hei_2$ (where $i_1$ and $i_2$ are the first and second biproduct inclusions) there is a morphism $h' : U \to V$ such that $h=xh'$.

If this is indeed your question, then here is an how to solve it.

(a) Show that there is a unique morphism $p : S\oplus T \to V$ such that $pi_1=j$ and $pi_2=k$.
(b) Show that $ve=xp$.
(c) Using (b) show that $p\text{ker}(e)=0$.
(d) Using that epis are normal epis (i.e. cokernels of some morphism and hence of their kernels) show that there is a unique morphism $h' : U\to V$ such that $h'e=p$.
(e) Show that $h = xh'$.

Comment: Thanks Nex, this is exactly how I solved it, the thin that caused me trouble was to realize step (c) of your answer.